# Searching in array that contains multiple objects on the basis of key's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search

I am trying to search for the total no. of occurrence of a value in an array on the basis of key.
I have already tried it using loop, which gave the correct answer.
Is there any other suitable way?

If I have array which conatins repeated **type:'page_title'** given as below:

```
  weddingData: Array<WeddingDataModel> = [
{
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello First element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello Second Element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello Third Element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello',
  }
},
{
  type: 'background_color',
  data: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff785'
  }
},
{
  type: 'banner_images',
  data: {
    image1 : {},
    image2: {},
    image3: {}
  }
}];
```

Now, how can I get the no. of count(s) of key 'page-title' present in weddingData array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use `filter` (*javascript* version):

```js
var weddingData = [
{
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello First element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello Second Element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello Third Element',
  }
},
 {
  type: 'page_title',
  data: {
    title: 'Hello',
  }
},
{
  type: 'background_color',
  data: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff785'
  }
},
{
  type: 'banner_images',
  data: {
    image1 : {},
    image2: {},
    image3: {}
  }
}];

console.log(weddingData.filter(x => x.type === 'page_title').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce:

```
var result = weddingData.reduce((amount, weddingDataItem) => {
    if (weddingDataItem.type === 'page_title') {
        return amount + 1;
    }
    return amount;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method for this simply.

```
weddingData.filter(p=>{return p.type === 'page_title'}).length;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily go into a `forEach` loop on the array, checking every type index, as shown:

```
weddingData.forEach( (element,key ) => { 
if (element.type == "page_title" )
    console.log(true)
    // count and do stuff here
else 
    console.log(false)
})
```

Hope this helps!